# How to encrypt stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, encryption, teradata

Is it possible to encrypt stored procedures in Teradata?
I would like to hide the code of procedure from others and I have no idea if it is even possible.

Some ideas?

Thanks,
Cris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to encrypt the source code of a SP in Teradata, you can simply use the `NO SPL` option and then no source code is stored.

Either during creation using ODBC, CLI or BTEQ, e.g. in BTEQ

```
.COMPILE FILE 'mysp.spl' WITH NOSPL
```

But the common way is to CREATE it first and then run:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mySP COMPILE WITH NO SPL;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you a lot! Just one more question: Can you somehow see the code of the procedure compiled with NO SPL option? I mean, somewhere is this code stored, right?

Comment: @Krzysztof: No, it's not stored anywhere on the DBMS, as it's not needed to call the Stored Procedure. An SP in Teradata is similar to an Embedded SQL program in C, i.e. the source code is converted to C (the SQL is still plain SQL) and compiled into a Shared Object (.so) on Linux. This .so is stored in the database and materialized (+cached) in the file system when you CALL the SP.